# What is This More General Almost-Traversal Operation

Tags: haskell, asynchronous, functional-programming, option-type, traversable

Trying to wrap my mind around traversals - or maybe something slightly different, in this case.

I understand a traversal to be an operation that performs an applicative operation (or effect) over a traversable structure.  So for example from [Data.Traversable](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html),

```
>>> mapM (\n -> [1..n]) $ Just 3
[Just 1,Just 2,Just 3]
```

Where `mapM` is just a form of `traverse` for monads.  So this takes a function `g` that returns a list ranging from 1 to the function's input, and a `Maybe`.  The result of traversing this list-returning function over the `Maybe Just` is the `Just` constructor applied to each element of the list ranging from 1 to the `3` contained in the original `Just`.  That's all well and good.

What I am wondering about is what if we generalize `g` a little bit.  In a traversal, `g` takes a value of type `a` matching the type contained in the `Traversable`, and returns an applicative of a result type `b`:

```
traverse :: Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> Const m a -> f (Const m b)
                             ----------
```

What if instead, `g` does not return merely `f b`, but instead returns the same type `f (Const m b)` that the overall operation returns -

```
?traverse-like? :: Applicative f => (a -> f (Const m b)) -> Const m a -> f (Const m b)
                                    --------------------
```

My specific context is this - I'm working in an application composing a series of `Maybe` computations with async effects, which operations themselves asynchronously return `Maybe`s.  So it looks something like

- start with a `Maybe` `m1`
- `traverse-like` an async operation over `m1`

  - if `m1` is `Nothing`, short-circuit out of the computation, i.e. `traverse-like` returns `m2 == Nothing` to the computation
  - if `m1` is `Just x`, perform the async effect which may return `async Nothing` or `async Just x`, s.t. `traverse-like` returns `m2 == Nothing` or `Just async x`
- `traverse-like` an async operation over `m2`...

The main utility of this operation is the flattening a `Maybe async Maybe` (obtained from traversing an `a -> async Maybe` operation) into a `Maybe async`.

This whole world is new to me (coming from an imperative background), so I apologize if I'm not even thinking about this correctly - but I hope the above example at least makes it clear what I am trying to accomplish.  It seems more general than a mere traversal, similarly to how `bind` is more general than `map` - but I don't know what the operation is actually called, or if it even makes sense beyond this particular use case.  If anyone with more experience in functional programming, Haskell, etc. could shed light on the nature of this operation, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Looks like you're traversing a `Const m a`, which doesn't contain any `a`s. So the `g` function won't ever be called; it can have any signature you like.

Comment: If I'm correctly understanding what you're saying in the second half of your post, it sounds like you might be looking for [`MaybeT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.0.4/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Maybe.html)

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson I think you might be right - I'll want to look into this.  Probably not exactly what I am doing, but rather a better way of doing it.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little unclear to me from your description of your use-case if you are describing two calls to `traverse-like` (one to process `m1` and another to process `m2`) or if you are describing a single `traverse-like` call that would recurse/iterate into processing `m2`.

If it's the one-step, non-recursive version you're after, then it's *possible* that you're looking for:

```
traverse2 :: (Applicative f, Monad m, Traversable m) => (a -> f (m b)) -> m a -> f (m b)
traverse2 f = fmap join . traverse f
```

When specialized to `m ~ Maybe`, it appears to do what you want:

```
traverse2 (...) Nothing = return Nothing
traverse2 (\i -> return Nothing) (Just 1) = return Nothing
traverse2 (\i -> return $ Just (i+1)) (Just 1) = return (Just 2)
```